# Enumeration of the complement subset

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request

Could you please suggest some books that could contain the following formula from elementary combinatorics?

Let $a_1,\ldots,a_p$ and $b_1,\ldots,b_q$ be some elements of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ such that $a_1<\dots<a_p$, $b_1<\dots<b_q$ and $\{b_1,\ldots,b_q\}=\{1,\ldots,n\}\setminus\{a_1,\ldots,a_p\}$.
In other words, we divide $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ into two disjoint subsets
and enumerate their elements in the ascending order.
Then for each $k$ in $\{1,\ldots,q\}$,
$$
b_k = k + |\{j\in\{1,\ldots,p\}\colon\ a_j - j < k\}|.
$$
I know that this simple formula is correct, I suspect that it should be well known, and I need a reference to it or a title of this formula. Unfortunately I am very far from combinatorics.